# Strange exceptions stack trace in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

[image]
Get next strange Xamarin Studio behaviour:
I throw hard-coded exception in specific line of some class.

[image]
Result is next:
catch exception always in Main class without my specific line in stack trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `OpenRelatedView()` seems to be called from a non-UI thread because you are using `InvokeOnMainThread()` in there. So my assumption is you are using `Task.Run()` somewhere to call it. All async code will implicitly be wrapped into a try-catch.

This exception must be caught and processed by you. Every `Task` object has got an `Exception` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) that will contain all the exceptions that happened during the async execution. If you are using `await` correctly, these exceptions will be unwrapped. Your method has a `void` return type so it cannot be awaited. Hence the exception will remain undetected until something takes care of it. On some platforms (windows Phone for instance) you will never notice that something went wrong.

With Xamarin.iOS however, there is handler for all uncaught exceptions at app root level, that's why you'll see the exception there.

Steven Clery has a lot of good [articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) about tasks ans async coding.