# xamarin exception doesn't show call stack

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am going a little crazy trying to figure out this error.
[image: Error shown]

After reading
[Strange exceptions stack trace in Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882527/strange-exceptions-stack-trace-in-xamarin-studio) 
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

I realize that the error is being wrapped at the root level. The issue is that I can't figure out where the error is coming from, since the call stack only shows the root. The error is reproducible, meaning that I take the same series of actions and it happens every time. But when I am debugging and step through it, the app just instantly closes (without showing a crash). The visual studio debugger still thinks its connected (its not). And it does so on a random and different line each time. When I don't put in a break point and let it run full speed I get the error shown in the pic. This happens in the iphone simulator and a real iphone. If I just run the app independently from visual studio it will just instant close each time just the same.

Any thoughts on how I can debug this? my Debug->Windows->Exception Settings have everything checked.

---EDIT----
I have a clue. See the top line in the error below. it looks like it is it

```
2023-07-18 14:58:31.368689-0400 <MYAPP>2.iOS[21002:184033] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/ios/release/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4570, condition `array->len == 1' not met
```

Every time it crashes it is on some sqlite call. for example the .FirstOrDefaultAsynx

```
database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(fileName);
await database.Table<Some table call>.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I finally realized there was additional debug in the output I was missing that make it seem like this is being thrown from the mono library

```
2023-07-18 14:58:31.368689-0400 <MYAPP>2.iOS[21002:184033] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/ios/release/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4570, condition `array->len == 1' not met

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1059f2235 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : 
    0x1059e664e - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : 
    0x1059f186f - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : 
    0x7ff8377405ed - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x0 - Unknown
    0x7ff800131e58 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x105c2f290 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type
    0x105bf6fd8 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105bf714f - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105bf718a - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/
Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105a52466 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105a6f2a6 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105a6f9e5 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105a5136d - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x106f2107f - Unknown
    0x11fec574a - Unknown
    0x11f77cedf - Unknown
    0x11fec35a3 - Unknown
    0x11ec0750b - Unknown
    0x11ec04ec3 - Unknown
    0x11ec0278b - Unknown
    0x11ebfabe6 - Unknown
    0x11ebfa74e - Unknown
    0x1059fc9a5 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105b23d9f - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105b6b01a - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105b68ce1 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105b742a3 - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC
7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x105b740ee - /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/938D4883-0489-469A-A1B7-9F29A266083B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/488BE31F-6002-4EEA-BEED-90E8BE242BC7/<MYAPP>2.iOS.app/<MYAPP>2.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x7ff83774d1d3 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_start
    0x7ff837748bd3 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : thread_start

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7ff8376f41f2):0x7ff8376f41e2  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 48 01 
00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  ...
....H...I....
0x7ff8376f41f2  73 08 48 89 c7 e9 df 9a ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 53  s.
H............S
0x7ff8376f4202  00 00 02 
49 89 ca 0f 05 73 08 48 89 c7 e9 c7 9a  ...I
....s.H.....
0x7ff8376f4212  ff ff 
c3 90 90 90 b8 83 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .
..........I....

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback <0x0015d>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool <0x000e2>
=================================================================
```

I have tried this with multiple versions of the sqllite library and many different open flags, especially around multi/single threading. All my nuget packages are up to date.

---EDIT---
ok so it went away without changing a single line of code. So even when I cleaned the solution, closed visual studio deleted the bin and object folders for all of the projects then rebuilt everything, it was still there. I found a bug report matching exactly. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/iOS-Crash---condition-array-gt;len-/157054?port=1025&fsid=127cfad8-d51b-4555-993e-c0b743bc436c&q=condition+%60array-%3Elen+%3D%3D+1%27+not+met&ref=native&refTime=1689716869920&refUserId=3fed7c8d-ac63-4b6e-a828-2e63afae421b

But that was closed due to not enough information. Since mine was reproducible, I tried to make a new project distilling down the minimal code so i could submit it. But the problem couldn't be replicated. Then opening up my original solution it was magically gone. Again without changing a single line. The problem with this is now I can't trust rebuilding the app for distribution. So I will have to go through full QA again just by switching to release.